# Dapper Postgres stored procedure with parameter

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

```
try
{
    return Connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<T>(sql, param, _transaction,
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
catch (Exception orig)
{
    var ex = new Exception($"Dapper proc execution failed!", orig);
    AddDetailsToException(ex, sql, param);
    throw ex;
}
```

With SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."GetChildBank"(
    "bankId" integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$

     )
     select * from cte where ParentBank is not null
                and "Id" <> "bankId"
$BODY$;
```

I am using Dapper with PostgreSQL and using stored procedure to get data
but it always throws errors.

It converts into a SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM "GetChildBank"("bankId" := $1)
```

which is wrong.

Comment: "but it always error" - what error? and what does `param` look like here; and **presumably** `sql` is the name of a stored procedure, in which case: what parameters are defined on it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the code of your stored procedure (or function) as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: to elaborate - I can almost certainly help here (I'm the primary dapper author/maintainer), but: I'm not psychic. You're going to have to help me here by telling me *at least* what `orig.Message` says. Any additional details would also be useful, but `orig.Message` is the **absolute minimum** I need to stand a chance here (in a perfect world: `orig.GetType().Name` would be nice, too, as would some info about what `sql` and `param` are - maybe something about what `T` is too)

Comment: @MarcGravell sql is store procedure name and param are parameter of store procedure

Comment: re the edit: `It converts into sql a statement SELECT * FROM "GetChildBank"("bankId" := $1) which is wrong` - no, that's simply not a thing that dapper does, at all. It doesn't convert anything into anything. So; let's take a step back: what is `sql` here? presumably `sql` is `"GetChildBank"`? and presumably `param` looks something like `new { bankId = 130134 }`? Now: what *actually happens*? What is `orig.Message`?

Comment: also: have you tested the stored procedure from your preferred database tool? i.e. can you execute `GetChildBank 130134` from the tools, and does it work? can I *see* what you're passing in `param`? it may be relevant

Comment: @MarcGravell orig.Message is "42809: GetChildBank(bankId => integer) is a procedure"

Comment: @MarcGravell i had tested this query it show result on database tool

Comment: and `sql` *really is* simply `"GetChildBank"` ? (it would be a lot easier if your example was explicit, i.e. `return Connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<T>("GetChildBank", new { bankId = 12345 }, _transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`)

Comment: @MarcGravell its not working for Postgresql

Comment: @AmolVasaikar "its not working for Postgresql" - that doesn't give me any more information; we had already concluded that something wasn't working, and that you're targeting Postgresql. Can you answer my specific question from immediately before?

Answer (score 2):

Dapper does not seem to be the problem here. To execute a stored procedure in postgresql with parameters it should be

```
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=root;Database=sample"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var sql = "CALL \"GetChildBank\"(@bankId)";
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.Add("@bankId", 11);
    var res = connection.Execute(sql, p);
}
```

To create a function that returns a row set and to callit from select, you need to use create function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ""GetChildBank"("bankId" integer) RETURNS SETOF cte AS $$
SELECT * FROM cte where "ParentBank" IS NOT NULL AND "Id" <> $1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createfunction.html